# From unix to Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, sed, awk

I am making a shell script where I am reading inputs from one file. File contains data 
123
1234
121

I am reading the inputs from this file using while read line do condition and putting all inputs in SQL statements.Now in my shell script i am going on SQL Prompt and running some queries. In one condition, I am using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STATEMENT` in SQL.
as

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE BKP_ACDAGENT4 as SELECT * FROM BKP_ACDAGENT WHERE DATASOURCEAGENTID IN ('123','1234','121')';
```

I want this to be execute, but somehow its not working.
Can anyone help me in executing it?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Error starting at line 13 in command:
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE BKP_ACDAGENT4 as SELECT * FROM BKP_ACDAGENT WHERE DATASOURCEAGENTID IN ('50183','50184')';
END;
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 106:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "50183" when expecting one of the following:

   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem return
   returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or
   like like2 like4 likec between into using || multiset bulk
   member submultiset
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Is it a quoting issue? Did you try changing the outer single quotes to double quotes?

Comment: Well what i've done is 

tr -s '\n' < /home/scripts/input.txt | sed "s/.*/'&'/g" | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/^\(.*\),$/\1/g' > /home/scripts/newinput.txt

Comment: yeah issue was with double quotes only...... I've changed from single to double quotes and its working :)....... THanks alot guys

Comment: You don't need to use `execute immediate` if you're bullding the `create` statement dynamically in your shell script anyway. The text you're executing has no bind variables or any other construction - it's effectively a static SQL statement by the time Oracle sees and tries to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the single quotes which you have used for the predicates in your `IN` list, that is the single quotes in

```
WHERE DATASOURCEAGENTID IN ('123','1234','121')';
```

are causing the issue here. You need to escape the single quotes using two single quotes

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE BKP_ACDAGENT4 as SELECT * FROM BKP_ACDAGENT  WHERE DATASOURCEAGENTID IN (''123'',''1234'',''121'')';
```

The above will work on all Oracle version.

If you're one Oracle 10g or above, you can use `q` keyword

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[CREATE TABLE BKP_ACDAGENT4 as SELECT * FROM BKP_ACDAGENT  WHERE DATASOURCEAGENTID IN ('123','1234','121')]';
```